Домашнее задание по Java проблема с абстрактным классом и внешним компаратором. Написал код почти работающий
Что нужно сделать
Выполните задание в репозитории java_basics в проекте AbstractClasses/practice_1. Директория пустая, вам необходимо в ней создать новый проект и выполнить задание.

Создайте класс компании Company, содержащей сотрудников и реализующей методы:

найм одного сотрудника — hire(Employee employee),
найм списка сотрудников – hireAll(Collection employes),
увольнение сотрудника – fire(Employee employee),
получение значения дохода компании – getIncome().
Каждый метод НЕ должен иметь модификатор static, это позволит каждому объекту класса Company иметь свой набора сотрудников, свой расчет дохода, увольнение и найм. Аргументы и возвращаемое значение методов выберите на основании логики работы вашего приложения.

Создайте два метода, возвращающие список указанной длины (count). Они должны содержать сотрудников, отсортированных по убыванию и возрастанию заработной платы:

List getTopSalaryStaff(int count),
List getLowestSalaryStaff(int count).

Создайте классы сотрудников с информацией о зарплатах и условиями начисления зарплаты:

Manager — зарплата складывается из фиксированной части и бонуса в виде 5% от заработанных для компании денег. Количество заработанных денег для компании генерируйте случайным образом от 115 000 до 140 000 рублей.
TopManager — зарплата складывается из фиксированной части и бонуса в виде 150% от заработной платы, если доход компании более 10 млн рублей.
Operator — зарплата складывается только из фиксированной части.
Каждый класс сотрудника должен имплементировать интерфейс Employee. В интерфейсе Employee должен быть объявлен метод, возвращающий зарплату сотрудника, — getMonthSalary().
Аргументы и возвращаемое значение метода выберите в соответствии с логикой начисления зарплат. В интерфейсе объявите необходимые методы.
Для демонстрации и тестирования работы ваших классов:
Создайте и наймите в компанию: 180 операторов Operator, 80 менеджеров по продажам Manager, 10 топ-менеджеров TopManager.
Распечатайте список из 10–15 самых высоких зарплат в компании.
Распечатайте список из 30 самых низких зарплат в компании.
Увольте 50% сотрудников.
Распечатайте список из 10–15 самых высоких зарплат в компании.
Распечатайте список из 30 самых низких зарплат в компании.
Еще не сказано что нужно написать  работающий компаратор. я по честному перелопатил варианты с кодом, но так и не нашел как составить компаратор так чтобы премия начислялась в соответствии с условием в классе   TopManager if ( company.getCompanyRevenue() > 10_000_000.0) , а не так как сейчас премия начисляется при Доходе компании : 800000.0 невзирая на условие в 10_000_000.0. Дайте зацепочку.

прошу подсказать как правильно задавать здесь вопросы, это мой первый опыт.
подскажите с решением.

import java.util.*;
public class Company {
    private double inCome = 0;
    List <Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
    public void  hire (Employee employee) {
        employees.add(employee);
    }
    public void  hireAll (List <Employee> employees) {
        for ( Employee e : employees) {
            hire(e);
        }
    }
    public void fire (Employee employee) {
        employees.remove(employee);
    }
    public double getInCome () {
        return inCome;
    }
    public List <Employee> getTopSalaryStaff (int count) {
        employees.sort(new SortByTopSalaryStaff());
        if (count < 0 && count > employees.size()) {
            List <Employee> EmptyList = new ArrayList<>();
            System.out.println("неверное количество");
            return EmptyList;
        }
        return employees.subList(0, count);
    }
    public List <Employee> getLowestSalaryStaff (int count) {
        employees.sort(new SortByLowestSalaryStaff());
        if (count < 0 && count > employees.size()) {
            List <Employee> EmptyList = new ArrayList<>();
            System.out.println("неверное количество");
            return EmptyList;
        }
        return employees.subList(0, count);
    }
    public double getCompanyRevenue () {

        for (Employee e : employees) {
            inCome = inCome + e.getRevenue();
        }
        return inCome;
    }

}

public interface Employee {
    double getMonthSalary ();
    double getRevenue();
}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Company company = new Company();
        List <Employee> workers = new ArrayList<>();
        Operator operator = new Operator();
        //Manager manager = new Manager();
        //TopManager topManager = new TopManager(company);
        company.hire(operator);
        for (int i = 0; i < 180; i++){
            workers.add(new Operator());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
            workers.add(new Manager());
            if ( i%8 == 0 ) {
                workers.add(new TopManager(company));
            }
        }
        company.hireAll(workers);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Количество работников : " + company.employees.size());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Доход компании : " + company.getCompanyRevenue());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("topSalaryStaff");
        System.out.println();

        List <Employee> topSalaryStaff = company.getTopSalaryStaff(12);
        for (Employee e: topSalaryStaff) {
            System.out.println(e.getMonthSalary());
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
/*
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("lowSalaryStaff");
        System.out.println();
        List <Employee> lowSalaryStaff = company.getLowestSalaryStaff(12);
        for (Employee e: lowSalaryStaff) {
            System.out.println(e.getMonthSalary());
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------");


 */

    }
}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Company company = new Company();
        List <Employee> workers = new ArrayList<>();
        Operator operator = new Operator();
        //Manager manager = new Manager();
        //TopManager topManager = new TopManager(company);
        company.hire(operator);
        for (int i = 0; i < 180; i++){
            workers.add(new Operator());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
            workers.add(new Manager());
            if ( i%8 == 0 ) {
                workers.add(new TopManager(company));
            }
        }
        company.hireAll(workers);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Количество работников : " + company.employees.size());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Доход компании : " + company.getCompanyRevenue());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("topSalaryStaff");
        System.out.println();

        List <Employee> topSalaryStaff = company.getTopSalaryStaff(12);
        for (Employee e: topSalaryStaff) {
            System.out.println(e.getMonthSalary());
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
/*
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("lowSalaryStaff");
        System.out.println();
        List <Employee> lowSalaryStaff = company.getLowestSalaryStaff(12);
        for (Employee e: lowSalaryStaff) {
            System.out.println(e.getMonthSalary());
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------");


 */

    }
}

public class Operator implements Employee {
    private  double salary = 30_000;
    final double income = 0;
    @Override
    public double getMonthSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    @Override
    public double getRevenue() {
        return income;
    }
}
import java.util.Comparator;
public class SortByLowestSalaryStaff implements Comparator<Employee> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Employee employee1, Employee employee2) {
        if (employee1.getMonthSalary() > employee2.getMonthSalary()) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (employee1.getMonthSalary() == employee2.getMonthSalary()) {
            return 0;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}

import java.util.Comparator;
public class SortByTopSalaryStaff implements Comparator <Employee> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Employee employee1, Employee employee2) {

        return Double.compare(employee2.getMonthSalary(), employee1.getMonthSalary());
    }





    /*
    @Override
    public int compare(Employee employee1, Employee employee2) {

        if (employee1.getMonthSalary() < employee2.getMonthSalary()) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (employee1.getMonthSalary() == employee2.getMonthSalary()) {
            return 0;
        }
        return -1;
    }

     */


}

import java.util.Random;
public class TopManager implements Employee{
    private  final Company company;
    private final double salary;
    private final double bonus = 1.5;
    private final double earnedLimit = 10_000_000.0;
    final double income = 0;
    public TopManager (Company company) {
        this.company = company;
        this.salary = 900000; // + new Random().nextInt(40000);
    }
    @Override
    public double getRevenue() {
        return income;
    }
    @Override
    public double getMonthSalary() {
       //double companyIncome = company.getCompanyRevenue();

        if ( company.getCompanyRevenue() > earnedLimit) {
            return  salary + salary * bonus;
        }
        return salary;
    }
}


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Читать нужно здесь. В коде слишком много проблем, решить каждую из них и написать работающую программу - это и есть цель задания.

как составить компаратор так чтобы премия начислялась в соответствии с условием в классе TopManager if ( company.getCompanyRevenue() > 10_000_000.0) , а не так как сейчас премия начисляется при Доходе компании : 800000.0 невзирая на условие в 10_000_000.0.

Или чего поменять чтобы премия начислялась как надо. В коде все восемь классов приведены. Все работает, все сортируется. Проблема только с начислением премии. Я в классе менеджер ручками доход менял. При сумме дохода компании 800 тысяч премия начисляется, хотя не должна. Как победить не знаю, только учусь.

Может просто есть конкретный человек который занимается наставлением на путь истинный таких дилетантов как я.

Основная ошибка в представленном коде -- некорректное вычисление выручки (revenue) компании в методе getCompanyRevenue(), где значение переменной inCome (данное название следует перевести как приБыль) НЕ обнуляется и соответственно "приБыль" будет нарастать при каждом вызове данного метода, то есть к примеру, при сортировке работников этот метод будет вызываться для каждого топ менеджера при сравнении его дохода с доходом любого другого сотрудника и "выручка" компании взлетит до небес.
Вероятно следовало закешировать вычисленное значение дохода, чтобы сократить количество ненужных вычислений:
public class Company {
    private Double income = null;

    // ...

    public double getCompanyRevenue () {
        if (null == income) {
            income = calcIncome();
        }
        return income.doubleValue();
    }

    protected double calcIncome() {
        double result = 0d;

        for (var emp : employees) {
            result += emp.getRevenue();
        }
        return result;
        // или так (Stream API) 
        // return employees.stream().mapToDouble(Employee::getRevenue).sum();
    }
}

Соответственно, при вызове других методов, которые изменяют штат / персонал компании, значение переменной income следует сбрасывать в null (исключительно в рамках данного учебного задания, предполагая, что эта программа однопоточная).

Дополнение
Может быть альтернативное решение без кеширования (дополнительной логики в геттере getCompanyRevenue), но в любом случае потребуется реализовать отдельный метод для вычисления суммарной выручки/прибыли, который следует не забывать вызывать вместо сеттера в нужный момент, например после заполнения коллекции всех сотрудников.
public class Company {
    // ...
    private double income = 0d;

    // простой геттер, без логики кеширования
    public double getCompanyRevenue() {
        return income;
    }

    public void calculateRevenue() {
        var result = 0d;
        
        for (var emp : employees) {
            result += emp.getRevenue();
        }
        this.income = result;
    }
    // ...
}

В классе Main следует вызвать этот метод после вызова hireAll перед сортировкой:
// ...
company.hireAll(workers);
company.calculateRevenue();


Кроме того, в представленном коде для всех сотрудников их "выручка", которая возвращается из метода getRevenue равна нулю, соответственно и выручка компании всегда будет нулевой.
Чтобы проверить возможность начисления бонусов для топ-менеджеров, нужно чтобы хотя бы операторы приносили 56К дохода при прочих входных данных.

Ещё одна типичная ошибка -- использование типа с плавающей точкой double для хранения результатов финансовых вычислений, где требуется фиксированная точность (например, до копейки).


Также в представленном коде можно улучшить реализацию методов getTopSalaryStaff, getLowestSalaryStaff в классе Company.
Во-первых, сортировку следует выполнять после проверки входного параметра count.
Во-вторых, условие if (count < 0 && count > employees.size()) бессмысленно и никогда не будет выполняться из-за неверной логической операции &&, подразумевающей, что count является отрицательным числом, большим нуля.  Следовало использовать оператор ИЛИ ||.
Кроме того, для неправильного аргумента имеет смысл выбрасывать соответствующее исключение типа IllegalArgumentException, а не возвращать пустой список.  Если же надо вернуть пустой список, лучше использовать стандартный метод Collections.emptyList, а не создавать каждый раз пустой модифицируемый список.
В-третьих, отдельные классы компараторов НЕ нужны со времени появления Java 8 в 2014 году, вместо них следует использовать статические методы Comparator::comparingDouble:
В-четвёртых, из указанных методов следует возвращать немодифицируемые списки при помощи Collections.unmodifiableList.
public List <Employee> getTopSalaryStaff (int count) {
    if (count <= 0 || count > employees.size()) {
        return emptyListOnError(count);
    }
    employees.sort(Comparator
        .comparingDouble(Employee::getMonthSalary)
        .reversed()
    );

    return Collections.unmodifiableList(employees.subList(0, count));
}

private static List<Employee> emptyListOnError(int count) {
    System.out.println("неверное количество: " + count);
    return Collections.emptyList();
}

Аналогично при помощи Stream API и определения двух статических компараторов:
private static final Comparator<Employee> byMonthSalary = Comparator.comparingDouble(Employee::getMonthSalary);

private static final Comparator<Employee> byMonthSalaryDesc = byMonthSalary.reversed();

public List <Employee> getTopSalaryStaff (int count) {
    return getNEmployees(count, byMonthSalaryDesc);
}

public List <Employee> getLowestSalaryStaff(int count) {
    return getNEmployees(count, byMonthSalary);
}

private List<Employee> getNEmployees(int count, Comparator<Employee> comparator) {
    return count <= 0 || count > employees.size() 
        ? emptyListOnError(count) 
        : employees.stream()
            .sorted(comparator)
            .limit(count)
            .toList();    
}


Благодарю, я кеширование ещё не изучал. Задача однопоточная, до многопоточности тоже ещё не дошёл. Теперь хоть понятно стало откуда ноги растут. Даже предположить не мог что сортировка доход прибавляет. Наверное здесь можно обойтись без "высоких технологий" Я подумаю как развязаться с этими методами.

Кеширование (запоминание вычисленного значения) выручки компании в данном случае необходимо, так как сортировка сама по себе "тяжелая" операция в плане производительности со сложностью O(N * log N), а если при этом добавляется вычисление в цикле по всей коллекции работников, сложность становится O(N^2 * log N).

Благодаря вашей помощи я решил поставленную задачу Всё работает можно сдавать. Но остались вопросы и мне очень хочется разобраться до конца.

Кроме того, для неправильного аргумента имеет смысл выбрасывать соответствующее исключение типа  IllegalArgumentException , а не возвращать пустой список. Если же надо вернуть пустой список, лучше использовать стандартный метод Collections.emptyList, а не создавать каждый раз пустой модифицируемый список. Что за IllegalArgumentException и как он работает и как с ним взаимодействовать? Документация по этому есть в недоступном для моего понимания виде.



статические методы Comparator::comparingDouble: по этому запросу в интернете только идет ответ Comparable и Comparator, как раз отдельные классы.
из указанных методов следует возвращать не модифицируемые списки при помощи Collections.unmodifiableList. для этого тоже документация в недоступном для моего понимания виде.
Немогли бы Вы либо пояснить, либо дать ссылки на понятную для новичков документацию.


@АндрейРацкевич, если появились другие вопросы, их следует задавать отдельно, а не в комментариях.  Не совсем понятно, как именно вы ищете информацию в гугле, например по запросу java что такое illegalargumentexception сразу же приводится ссылка на статью в JavaRush Кофе-брейк #220. Как исправлять исключения в Java...: IllegalArgumentException — это тип RuntimeException, который возникает, когда метод вызывается с недопустимым или неподходящим аргументом.

Низкий Вам поклон.
Задача решена, пробелы в знаниях устранены. И ресурсом научили пользоваться.
Вопросов в рамках данной задачи нет.
